# Getting out of memory even with release while reading file in chunks to NSData

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm reading a file on my disk (which can be few GB in size) in 10MB chunks to verify MD5 for it. Method fetchRecords has been simplified as it is a bi

---

t long. The problem is that the data is released when fetchRecords method returns, by then I have few GB in memory. If file is big enough, it causes a crash. `[dataChunk release]` at the end does not help. Getting a lot of inactive memory until it returns.

[image]
[image]

```
- (void)fetchRecords
{    
    for (DownloadChunkInfo *downloadChunkInfo in [downloadFileInfo chunk])
    {
        NSData *dataChunk = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileDownloadPath withStartOffset:[downloadChunk startingByte] andEndOffset:[downloadChunk endingByte]];
        if ([dataChunk length] == [downloadChunk length])
        {
            if ([downloadChunk md5] && [[dataChunk MD5] isEqualToString:[downloadChunk md5]])
            {
                // Some code
            }
            else
            {
                // Some code
            }
        }
        [dataChunk release];
    }
}

+ (NSData *)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path withStartOffset:(off_t)startOffset andEndOffset:(off_t)endOffset
{
    FILE *file = fopen([path UTF8String], "rb");
    if(file == NULL)
        return nil;
    uint64_t size = (endOffset - startOffset) + 1;
    void *data = malloc(size);  // check for NULL!
    fseeko(file, startOffset, SEEK_SET);
    size_t realSize = fread(data, 1, size, file);  // check return value, in case read was short!
    fclose(file);

    // NSData takes ownership and will call free(data) when it's released
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:realSize];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`[dataChunk release]` is actually wrong, because you don't "own" the object returned by

```
NSData *dataChunk = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:...];
```

The return value is (subject to possible optimizations made by the compiler) 
an "autoreleased" object, which is released only when the current autorelease pool
is destroyed.

Therefore, using a local autorelease pool should help:

```
for (DownloadChunkInfo *downloadChunkInfo in [downloadFileInfo chunk])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData *dataChunk = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileDownloadPath withStartOffset:[downloadChunk startingByte] andEndOffset:[downloadChunk endingByte]];
        // do something with dataChunk ...
    }
}
```

For more information, see

- ["Basic Memory Management Rules"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1)
- ["Using Autorelease Pool Blocks"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

in the "Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide" for more information.